# Gitignore : Is it possible to ignore all files with at least one special character?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is such a .gitignore rule possible?

*Example:*

```
HélloWorld.txt
HelloWorld.txt
çow.txt
cow.txt
```

*It would only be tracked:*

```
HelloWorld.txt
cow.txt
```

**What I tried:**

Write `*[ç]*` in .gitignore file, and strangely enough, it works. Same with other special characters such as `*[é]*` or `*[à]*`. 
But I don't understand why !

Another thing, if it helps:
When I do a git status of my files, the logs are :

```
HelloWorld.txt
"H\303\251lloWorld.txt"
cow.txt
"\303\247ow.txt"
```

Someone to solve this mystery?

Comment: Likely, it treated `*[ç]*` as a bracket expression containing the bytes C3 and 87, not the single Unicode character U+00A7, so it matched all file names containing UTF-8 sequences containing either C3 (which would be U+00C0 through U+00FF) or A7 (which would be some set of characters less easily summarized: maybe those matching U+xxx7?).

Comment: Following links from [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) you end up it [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) (see "Character classes") so it isn't an undocumented glitch or anything like that.